# Debug typescript with visual studio code

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

I use this configuration in launch.json file to debug my server file .js, but it doesn't work with typescript file:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Avvia programma",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\www",
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "developement",
        "DEBUG": "node-rest:*"
    },
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "outFiles": []
}
```

putting a breakpoint i receive this message: "Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found”

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I also have a tsconfig.aot.js file (if i'm not wrong, it need for build):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./public/js/app"
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es5",
    "dom"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

I tried several solution found here, but nothing worked.
Thanks for any tip.

Max